# Compare values from two models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two models, Prediction and Correlation. I want to compare the Variable column in correlation with the Topcorrelators column in Prediction. If both the values are the same, I want to fetch the SHAP_abs value in front of Topcorrelators. Not sure if I am doing something wrong here.

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    @foreach(explode(',', $detail->Topcorrelators) as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $row }}
            </td>
            @foreach($Correlations_list as $corr)
                @if($corr->Variable == $row )
                    <td>
                        {{ $corr->SHAP_abs }}
                    </td> 
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(Prediction $detail) 
{
    $Correlations_list = Correlation::all();

    return view('admin.members.Detailspage',compact('detail','Correlations_list'));    
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @YasinPatel its returning blank...not able to get the values

Comment: @YasinPatel getting the Topcorrelators in table but the Correlation values is not fetching from db

Comment: @YasinPatel When I am simply trying to echo the values of correlations they are getting displayed but I guess there some error with my if condition